# Desktop freezes when trying to switch to another user

Tags: 11.10, gnome, login

I'm using ubuntu 11.10 gnome classic with 2 accounts admin and guest, if i try to switch users ubuntu log me out then get me into the login screen where guest and admin accounts are.

While being in admin or guest (either way) trying to log into the other account ubuntu freezes and cant login into second (whether admin or guest) account.

any ideas what to do to fix the issue so i can change users as normal?

Update: Here is a bug report about the issue. 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity-greeter/+bug/835310
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1861715&page=2
To solve it: 
sudo apt-get remove libpam-smbpass
And reboot.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see all we can do is look forward to an update or a fix, as I have performed numerous installs and switching users are problematic in all installs.

I haven't seen an official status of the bug just reports of the problem on various forums and that it happens with me on every install.  So far logging out then logging in as a different user appears to work without problems.  But any attempt to have two X users logged in at the same time doesn't work in 11.10.

So specifically, there isn't a current fix.  You can't change users as normal.  You need two computers to have two users logged into Ubuntu 11.10 X at the same time.